# PHP mySQL select query using array values

Tags: php, mysql

I have created an array from checkboxes seleced in a form. I want to construct a select query to present only these fields(=array values).
I'm stuck on query. This is what I have:

```
<form name="myForm" method="get">

 <input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="idStudent">ID<br><input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="FirstName">First Name<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="LastName">Last Name<br><input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="City">City<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="Phone">Phone<br><input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="6">Cell Phone<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="7">email<br><br>

 <input type="submit"  value="Search">

 </form> 

 <?php 

$checked = $_GET['chk1'];
for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++){
    echo "Selected " . $checked[$i] . "<br/>";
}
$ids = join(',',$checked);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Students;

?>
```

What should I put instead of the * in the query?
Thanks

Comment: The asterisk is a shorthand for all columns, so if you would want only 4 columns/fields (those containing id, last name, phone and email) state those specific columns.

Comment: @Mno instead of the * I want to place the array values. They hold the db column names based in the user's selection